# Example of smooth function of a smooth submanifold cannot be obtained by restriction of a smooth function in the manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Anyone can give the example of smooth function of a smooth submanifold N of M cannot be obtained by restriction of a smooth function in the smooth manifold M?

Comment: Consider the function $f(x) := \frac{1}{x}$ on the smooth submanifold $(0, \infty)$ of the smooth manifold $\Bbb R$. Since $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = +\infty$, $f$ cannot even be extended continuously to any proper superset of $(0, \infty)$ in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @Travis can we find smooth function in M whose and an open set in V such that restriction of f on i(V) matches with given smooth function. where i is imbedding of N into M

Comment: @Sushil Trivially, yes, by taking $V := \varnothing$ and any function. More interestingly, we can do this for any subset $V \subseteq N$ closed in $M$ using bump functions and in fact further insist that $f \vert_{M - N} = 0$. NB this statement assumes that we assume our manifolds are paracompact---typically we require manifolds to be second countable, and this is sufficient.

Comment: @Travis http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1489285/168520

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $f(x) := \frac{1}{x}$ on the smooth submanifold $\Bbb R_+ := (0, \infty)$ of the smooth manifold $\Bbb R$. Since $\lim_{x \to 0^+} = +\infty$, $f$ cannot even be extended continuously to any proper superset of $\Bbb R_+$ in $\Bbb R$.